# CodeIgniter URL Routing with RegEx numbers and alphabet

Tags: php, regex, codeigniter

I need a RegEx for arguments that combines numbers(0-9) and alphabets(a-z or A-Z).

Here is my route

```
$route['(:any)/PhotoDetails/(:any)'] = 'profile/PhotoDetails/$1/$2';
```

Comment: `([\w]+)/([\w]+)` should do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible regx are:-

```
$route['([\w]+)/PhotoDetails/([\w]+)'] = 'profile/PhotoDetails/$1/$2';
```

but there is a flow in above expression it could accept "_" as well since your routes contains only alphanumeric charactors so please use following route.

```
$route['([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/PhotoDetails/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)'] = 'profile/PhotoDetails/$1/$2';
```